# GCS connector in PySpark not reading CSV

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-storage, hadoop2, google-cloud-dataproc

The error I am getting is -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS.<init>()
```

this is simple code which used to work fine in past but recently this is the error I am getting while trying to read the CSV stored on the GCS bucket, I have proper jars downloaded from the Google Cloud website but I am unable to run it successfully please help by telling me what am i doing wrong.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .master('local[*]') \
  .appName('spark-gcs-demo') \
  .getOrCreate()
bucket = "testBucket"
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', "bucket") ####temporary 
import os  
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r"<pathtoJSON>"
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl', 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
# This is required if you are using service account and set true, 
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable', 'true')
df= spark.read.csv("gs://bucket/iris.csv")
```

The error I am getting:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:559)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:559)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:638)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this exception because of GCS connector misconfiguration.

You have set `fs.gs.impl` Hadoop property to `com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS`, but it should be set to `com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem`, or you can even omit this property, because [Hadoop can discover FS implementation class](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/rel/release-3.3.0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#L3356:L3367) using [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: Hi Igor , i tried the solution which you mentioned it is still giving the same issue , i wanted to understand what is the difference between the two classes you mentioned -  *.GoogleHadoopFileSystem vs *.GoogleHadoopFS

Comment: These 2 classes implement Hadoop's [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [AbstractFileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/AbstractFileSystem.html) respectively, that's why you need to configure them differently. 
Refer to [GCS connector documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/v2.1.5/gcs/INSTALL.md#configure-spark) to configure it properly with Spark.

Comment: is there any documentation where they specifically tell you which gcs-connector-hadoop2 jar is configured for use with which ? ?  , it's all so confusing on their git repo .

Comment: It's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#other_sparkhadoop_clusters